# Solving a diophantine equation involing squares and a prime number

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have the following diophantine equation

I wish to find and prove that there is ONLY ONE solution to the following equation

$x^2=y^2 + 31$

I understand that 31 is a prime number thus we can equate

$x^2 - y^2$ is a perfect square therefore we can write

$(x-y)* (x+y) =  31$

However I am lost as to what to do after this part.

Comment: Hint: The only ways to write the prime $31$ as a product are $1*31$, $-1*-31$, $31*1$, or $-31*-1$.

Comment: I still am unsure, on how to equate the two to get a value for x and y

Comment: Take each of the 4 cases, then solve the system of equations you get. E.g. for $1 \times 31=31$ you have two possibilities: $x+y=1, x-y=31$ or $x+y=31, x-y=1$. Do you know how to solve such systems of equations?

Comment: I got it thanks The answer is 15 and 16